# Idiomatic way to create a vector of pointers in C++11?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, vector

Let's say I want to create an `std::vector` of 10 pointers in C++11, each pointing to a default-constructed instance of class `Foo`. Here is one way to do it:

```
std::vector<Foo*> foos;
for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i) {
    foos.push_back(new Foo());
}
```

Is there an idiomatic way to avoid the `for` loop?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to avoid the explicit `for` loop, then yes, there is a way.

Use [`std::generate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate) or [`generate_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n):

```
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(foos), 10, [] { return new Foo(); });
```

That looks idiomatic.

Well, loop or not, it is almost a choice. But raw pointers are not recommended anymore, because it is very difficult to avoid leaking them without RAII. Use smart pointers such as `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` depending on the need.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> foos;
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(foos), 10, [] { return std::unique_ptr<Foo>(new Foo()); });
```

In C++14, you can use [`std::make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique). So you can abondon `new` completely.

Hope that helps.

Comment: How would you initialize a smart pointer without using ``new``? Have I missed something?

Comment: @JonasWielicki: Well, I meant, without wrapping it in a smart pointer. In C++14, you can do that without using `new`.

Comment: @Nawaz: Yes, that's what I was after. Thanks!

Comment: @Nawaz thank you for the explanation, didn't know about that feature of C++14.

Comment: Note that writing a (simpler) `make_unique` in C++11 is relatively easy: `template<typename T, typename... Args> std::unique_ptr<T> my_make_unique(Args&& args) { return {new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)}; }`.  The C++1y `make_unique` does some fancy stuff with `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` support, from what I can tell.

Answer (score 8):

> Is there an idiomatic way to avoid the `for` loop?

Not really. However, your code is *not* idiomatic C++11 because it uses `new` without `unique_ptr`. Don’t do that. In fact, as of C++14, you should consider conventional use of `new` deprecated in normal code (since C++14 introduces `make_unique`).

Comment: Or better, use Stephen T. Lavavej's version. http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3656.txt

Answer (score 1):

No one mentioned standard algorithm std::generate_n. So you can write

```
const size_t N = 10;

std::vector<foo *> foos;
foos.reserve( N );

std::generate_n( std::back_inserter( foos ), N, [] { return new foo(); };
```

Of course in fact it is the same loop.:)

Comment: I am sorry. When I was writing my post someone already pointed out std::generate_n.:)